# Is 門 read as かど or もん?

Tags: vocabulary, kanji, pronunciation

Is it more common to read 門 as かど or もん?

e.g. how would we pronounce the 門 in 彼らは門が開くのを待っていた。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the kanji character 門 is used as a noun in itself (meaning a gate), it is usually read as もん, although it was also read as かど in older time.  As other people say, 門 in your example should be read as もん in the modern Japanese.

The most common example of 門 read as かど in the modern Japanese that I can think of is a proverb 笑う門には福来る (わらうかどにはふくきたる).  This 門 is read as かど and means a house.  The literal meaning of the proverb is “Happiness comes to a home where family is laughing.”  [Progressive Waei Chū Jiten](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E7%AC%91%E3%81%86&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0) suggests two translations of this proverb: the more literal one is “Fortune favors cheerful homes,” and the less literal one is “Laugh and grow fat.”

Answer (score 4):

I think that もん is the word you mean, and かど is used mostly (only?) in names.

Comment: かど is the more archaic reading, which is why you see it mostly in names: it survives as a historical artifact. When read alone, it's always もん, as in 門を通って右 -> もんをとおってみぎ (take a right after the gate).

Answer (score 2):

I think もん is Chinese reading and かど　is Japanese reading .

You would found かど is usually used for the Classic Movies

for example...

みかど(mikado)「御門」

かどまつ(kadomatu)「門松」

かどで(kadode)「門出」

かどうき(kadowaki)「門脇」（name）

Comment: how would we pronounce the 門 in 彼らは門が開くのを待っていた。

Comment: In above is read as もん